# VM: _UITextContainerView (CALayer) - Memory Spike

Tags: ios, uitableview, instruments

I am working on an App with a `UITableViewController` using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to display an activity feed. Each cell has three UITextViews.

I'm seeing a large memory spike as can be seen in the instruments run. This often leads to the App being killed by iOS.

What is a `_UITextContainerView (CALayer)`?
How can I avoid this spike?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: In my case, I ended up switching to a UILabel which uses much less memory. The memory spike was happening during the animation of a table view. For example, when you add new records using a fetched results controller or the user taps the status bar to return to the top of the table view.

Comment: hmmm ok, thanks. I most likely wont be able to do this since I need to linkify certain parts of the text. Thanks though!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel

Comment: hmm, I will most likely need to scroll this text as well since it will be super long sometimes. I will take a look though. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem with an App with a `UITableViewController` using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and a `UITextView` that when I set the text content it would quickly explode in memory in the Profiler and exit due to memory pressure.

But for me it seems to be a bug in the OS due to having a custom class extending from `UITextView`. Once I removed that class and referred to the `UITextView` directly in UI and code, and then did all the formatting on the `UITextView` directly memory did not grow unbounded.

Hope that helps!